# Unfinished stubbing detected here when doThrow

Tags: java, junit

I try to throw an exception but I have this error.
I also try with `new LockException()` and `stubVoid` and `when.thenThrow` but is same.

```java
@Test    
public void TestAfterSave() {

    Locker locker = Mockito.mock(Locker.class);
    LockKey lockKey = new LockKey(TablesGaston.L_ARTICLE, "", 0);
    doThrow(LockException.class).when(locker).lock(contexte, lockKey);
}
```

```
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

Comment: This looks ok, so the problem is probably elsewhere (e.g. something unfinished a `@Before` method).  Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?